# Why python run tool window tab not showing the whole result?

Tags: python, json, printing, missing-data

I'm rather new to programming and I'm trying to print a json file but when i run the program only the last x lines show up.

The code looks like this:

```
import json
import pprint

f = open("practice02.json",)
data = json.load(f)

pprint.pprint(data)
```

(No errors in the end, if i abort the program immediately after the start i can catch the first lines. I thought the file is too big but this practice file is 0,45MB and i would like to work with the whole 100-200MB files)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. Your terminal's buffer is not big enough to hold everything you printed out. How do you expect to work with a 100MB file on the terminal? You should probably write the `pprint` output to a file and use a text viewer to work with it.

Comment: Is this code just to test that you can load the data? Because the result of `pprint.pprint` on data from a JSON file is not going to look very much different from the original file.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I only want to understand why is it not working, because with this code it prints out the whole:
    import json

    with open("practice02.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    data2 = json.dumps(data, indent=1)

    print(data2)

but with higher indent than 1 it shows the same incomplete result